# ArrayList vs Vector performance in single-threaded application

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, collections

I was just looking for the answer for the question why ArrayList is faster than Vector and i found ArrayList is faster as it is not synchronized. 
so my doubt is:

1. If ArrayList is not synchronized why would we use it in multithreaded environment and compare it with Vector.
2. If we are in a single threaded environment then how the performance of the Vector decreases as there is no Synchronization going on as we are dealing with a single thread.

Why should we compare the performance considering the above points ?

Please guide me :)

Comment: 1st [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12983286/3337714)

Comment: You can use the arraylists in a single thread to get the "speed" boost, but as soon as you need to transfer arraylists between threads you need to have synchronized lists. I usually push an arraylist when im done with it in a linkedblockingqueue for another thread to put it in and do its thing and eventually post its result back via another linkedlbockingqueue. Thing to remember is, when you are done with the list, dont touch it again in that thread.

Answer (score 3):

1. a) Methods using ArrayList in a multithreaded program may be synchronized.

   class X {

   ```
   List l = new ArrayList();

   synchronized void add(Object e) {
       l.add(e);
   }
   ...
   ```

   b) We can use ArrayList without exposing it to other threads, this is when ArrayList is referenced only from local variables

   void x() {
       List l = new ArrayList();  // no other thread except current can access l
       ...
2. Even in a single threaded environment entering a synchronized method takes a lock, this is where we lose performance

   ```
   public synchronized boolean add(E e) { // current thread will take a lock here
       modCount++;
   ```

   ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList` in a multithread environment if the list is not shared between threads.

If the list is shared between threads you can synchronize the access to that list.

Otherwise you can use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to get a List that can be used thread safely.

`Vector` is an old implementation of a synchronized List that is no longer used because the internal implementation basically synchronize every method. Generally you want to synchronize a **sequence of operations**. Otherwyse you can throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating the list another thread modify it. In addition synchronize every method is not good  from a performance point of view.

In addition also in a single thread environment accessing a synchronized method needs to perform some operations, so also in a single thread application Vector is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a component is single threaded doesn't mean that it cannot be used in a thread safe context.  Your application may have it's own locking in which case additional locking is redundant work.

Conversely, just because a component is thread safe, it doesn't mean that you cannot use it in an unsafe manner.  Typically thread safety extends to a single operation.  E.g. if you take an Iterator and call next() on a collection this is two operations and they are no longer thread safe when used in combination.  You still have to use locking for Vector. Another simple example is

```
private Vector<Integer> vec = 

vec.add(1);
int n = vec.remove(vec.size());
assert n == 1;
```

This is atleast three operations however the number of things which can go wrong are much more than you might suppose.  This is why you end up doing your own locking and why the locking inside Vector might be redundant, even unwanted.

For you own interest;

- `vec` can change at any point t another Vector or `null`
- `vec.add(2)` can happen between any operation, changing the size and the last element.
- `vec.remove()` can happen between any operation.
- `vec.add(null)` can happen between any operation resulting in a possible `NullPointerException`

The `vec` can `/* change */` in these places.

```
private Vector<Integer> vec = 

vec.add(1); /* change*/
int n = vec.remove(vec.size() /* change*/);
assert n == 1;
```

In short, assuming that just because you used a thread safe collection your code is now thread safe is a big assumption.

A common pattern which breaks is

```
for(int n : vec) {
   // do something.
}
```

Look harmless enough except

```
for(Iterator iter = vec.iterator(); /* change */ vec.hasNext(); ) {
   /* change */ int n = vec.next();
```

I have marked with `/* change */` where another thread could change the collection meaning this loop can get a ConcurrentModificationException (but might not)

> there is no Synchronization

The JVM doesn't know there is no need for synchronization and so it still has to do something.  It has an optimisation to reduce the cost of uncontended locks, but it still has to do work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basic concept to know answer for your above questions...

When you say array list is not syncronized and vector is, we mean that the methods in those  classes (*like add(), get(), remove() etc...*) are synchronized in vector class and not in array list class. These methods will act upon tha data being stored .

So, the data saved in vector class cannot be edited / read parallely as add, get, remove metods are synchornized and the same in array list can be done parallely as these methods in array list are not synchronized...

This parallel activity makes array list fast and vector slow... This behavior remains same though you use them in either multithreaded  (or) single threaded enviornment...

Hope this answers your question...